# Why carrier wave cannot transfer information?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, information

In the concept of wave modulation, I'm having trouble to understand why carrier wave cannot transfer information. My assumption is that the reason for that is due to the fact that the frequency, amplitude, and phase of that wave is constant we cannot identify change in the signal (i.e transfer it to $1$'s and $0$'s). But I know what EM wave has natural broadness (and many more kind of broadness depend on how you generate that EM wave) so there is some bandwidth to the frequency of the carrier wave which imply that we can identify some changes. After all we do see the light from monochromatic  lasers.

Comment: Information is something you do NOT know ahead of time. What information is not given in a carrier wave? If the amplitude is unknown you are talking about AM (amplitude modulation), if the frequency it is FM, if the phase  PM. Well, which one or ones? What do you mean by "broadness", FM noise, PM noise? If the transmitter does not know it can it be called information?

Comment: But a laser that is steadily on does not convey information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there is some bandwidth to the frequency of the carrier wave which imply that we can identify some changes.

That bandwidth is very thin and carries noise. Modulating the carrier wave with any useful information and receiving it successfully means it is not just the noisy carrier wave anymore, but it has modulation distinguishable from the noise.

Ideal carrier wave like linearly polarized plane wave does transmit *some* information in the most general sense, because we can infer frequency and direction to the emitter from it, and its polarization. This is not a useful information for the purposes of general communication though(a message) - it's an artifact of the method of communication.

One could try to encode useful information for the purpose of general communication by varying these artifacts, e.g. by varying frequency or polarization of the carrier wave. But then the result won't be the usual noisy carrier wave, but a modulated wave, like the AM/FM waves are.

> After all we do see the light from monochromatic lasers.

Lasers are not exactly monochromatic, their spectrum is comb-like, but even if light of single frequency was filtered out, similar to the ideal carrier wave, this could be visible (if in visible range, and strong enough, which lasers usually are). But light being visible has nothing to do with information; monochromatic wave is visible even if it carries no useful message.

Comment: I guess I have some misunderstood in what is defined "information". I think on it as "Log(number of states)" which is definitely not zero for laser or any other kind of carrier wave (since there is broadening)

Comment: The "(number of states)" in that definition is the number of distinguishable macroscopic states in the receiver after the transmission is received (in theory of communication, the number of possible messages). Noisy laser light or a real carrier wave have, in classical EM theory, infinite number of degrees of freedom and thus carry infinite *data* in any finite segment, but since this is all noise not encoding sender's message, it is, either by luck or by designer's intent, below the receiver's threshold of detection (the noise has to be weak enough, for the receiver to detect correctly).

Comment: So the number of possible messages when the sender does not modulate the carrier wave is 1 - the only message is "the carrier wave is on". Morse code transmissions have to turn the periodic wave on and off to transmit any more informative message. This is a kind of modulation of the periodic wave, which makes the resulting wave to be non-periodic, and have broader spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

A truly carrier wave is a single frequency and fixed amplitude. Therefore the only information you can extract from it is its frequency, amplitude, and maybe phase.

In communications we convey data by changing some combination of the frequency amplitude and phase in time. A carrier wave on its own has no variation in these parameters in time so it can be used to send symbolic data.

The questions ask about practical broadness of the carrier wave. This is irrelevant and doesn’t even quite make sense. The idealized carrier wave (and what we mean by the carrier wave) is the truly monochromatic idealized tone. If there is noise that broadens it in practice we say the carrier is broadened by noise. This noise can’t carry signal because, by definition, it is noise and we don’t control its content. If we did control its content we wouldn’t call it noise, we would call it signal, and we would say the carrier is modulated with our signal. Bottom line: the carrier wave is monochromatic.

Answer (score 0):

A carrier wave cannot carry information because it is constructed as such.  As you point out with the "natural broadness" of an EM wave, all practical waves can be used to convey information.

The concept of modulation breaks up a practical EM wave into an idealized carrier wave (which cannot carry information because its perfectly predictable), and a modulation of said wave which conveys the information.  It doesn't change the wave, it merely makes it easier to compute important information like channel capacity.

Answer (score 0):

A carrier wave *can* transmit information, simply by *turning it on and off according to a code*. In radio parlance this transmission mode is called CW, for *continuous wave*. This on-and-off switching of the carrier is used to transmit information in for example *Morse Code*.